# How to get more control over updating manifest file + provisioning azure resources via Teams Toolkit?

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

Recently I had a chance to build Team apps using Teams Toolkit (VSC). I love it. However, I have a couple of questions.

1. How to use existing Azure Ad app and existing bot when creating a Team app [messaging extension or Teams Tab with SSO enable].
2. How to use existing Azure resources, for example, Storage account, etc

Comment: Please go through this [Authenticate users in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/authentication) to understand the authentication process. It also includes how to use the app registration and bot for SSO in tab, bot, messaging extension.

Please follow this [Connect an app to Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/connect-an-app-to-azure-storage/) tutorial to understand how we can connect a storage account resource to an application.

Answer (score 0):

For using existing AAD app, you can refer to this [page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/wiki/Using-existing-Azure-AD-app-in-TeamsFx-project). You can also try to edit AAD manifest as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/aad-manifest-customization).

For using existing Bot, you can refer to this [page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/blob/dev/docs/fx-core/bot-help.md#how-to-reuse-existing-aad-in-toolkit-v2).

For using existing Azure resource, you can refer to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/provision#customize-resource-provision) to customize your Bicep files. Note that your need to ensure that the resource group you select when provision is the same as existing resource.

Comment: Thank you for the above links. I will definitely go ahead and use the above in my next Teams app.